# MediaPlayer, ProgressBar

Tags: android, seekbar

Is this the correct way to update a ProgressBar when playing Media? I figured there would be a callback in MediaPlayer, but I couldn't find it.

```
mediaPlayer.start();
final SeekBar progress = (SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
progress.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
new CountDownTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration(), 250) {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    progress.setProgress(progress.getProgress() + 250);
  }
  public void onFinish() {}
}.start();
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at **[android.widget.MediaController](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/MediaController.java#409)**, it has a progress bar.

They use a handler that recursively calls itself if appropriate. You can set the delay to however often you want the progress bar updated.

Note that the controller can be shown or hidden as well as dragged by the user, and - of course - the video can stop. These are the reasons for the various checks (`!mDragging && mShowing && mVideoView.isPlaying()`) before another recursive call to update the bar.

```
protected Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        int pos;
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            // ...

            case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                pos = setProgress();
                if (!mDragging && mShowing && mVideoView.isPlaying())
                {
                    msg = obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                    sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 - (pos % 1000));
                }
                break;

             // ...
        }
    }
};
```

To start it off use:

```
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
```

It will stop by itself, but you should cancel the last pending request using:

```
mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
```

Comment: Thanks, precisely, what I was looking for.

Comment: @pouzzler - You're welcome! Looking at the MediaController class is great for giving you ideas on making a custom controller.

Comment: Second link is gone because of a DMCA takedown: https://github.com/OESF/OHA-Android-4.0.1_r1.0

Answer (score 23):

Personally, I start off a Thread that checks `getCurrentPosition()` every 200ms or so until the `onCompletion()` event gets fired off:

```
private class MediaObserver implements Runnable {
  private AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  public void stop() {
    stop.set(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (!stop.get()) {
      progress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
      Thread.sleep(200);
    }
  }
}

private MediaObserver observer = null;

public void runMedia() {
  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
      observer.stop();
      progress.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    }
  });
  observer = new MediaObserver();
  mediaPlayer.start();
  new Thread(observer).start();
}
```

Comment: The timer doesn't block the UI so I suppose it's in another thread. So I suppose it's the same. I wish I was intelligent enough to figure these things out.

Comment: @pouzzler Countdown timer runs in another thread, the only difference is that it  doesn't use the actual progress.  I'll write up a threaded example

Comment: ah no need, I get it. Thanks :)

Comment: Same problem as before, I used your suggestion... with CountDownTimer: progress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()); - still no clue which is best ;) And off to bed for me and my philosophical questions.

Comment: Sorry I flagged the other answer, since it is more useful for everyone, even though I will stay with my non-ICS stuff for now.

Comment: Why did you use an atomic operation for the bool in your example?

Comment: @tobi.b In this instance it's probably not necessary, since only the observer thread is manipulating the stop variable and it's using pure assignment.  In general though, using atomic types prevents thread collisions where multiple threads are trying to manipulate a variable at the same time, so it's a habit

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener's method is named onCompletion(), not onComplete()

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is to use JRaymond's answer and [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

```
private class MediaObserver implements Runnable {
    private AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    public void stop() {
        stop.set(true);
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        while (!stop.get()) {
            try {
              if (player.isPlaying())
                 sendMsgToUI(player.getCurrentPosition(),
                             player.getDuration());
            } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try { 
              Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}

private MediaObserver observer = null;

public void runMedia() {
    observer = new MediaObserver();
    new Thread(observer).start();
}

//handles all the background threads things for you
private void sendMsgToUI(int position) {
    ChangingEvent event = new ChangingEvent(position);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
}
```

ChangingEvent class would look something like that:

```
public class ChangingEvent {
  private int position;

  public ChangingEvent(int position) {
      this.position= position;
  }

  public int getPosition() {
      return position;
  }
}
```

and in your Activity or Fragment all you have to do is

```
class YouClass extends Activity {
  private EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
}

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //your code
    eventBus.register(this);
}
//eventbus that updates UI
public void onEventMainThread(ChangingEvent event) {
    //seekbar or any other ui element
    seekBar.setProgress(event.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: I like this approach but I think you forgot to add loop/while that makes run()  being executed more than just once

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for noticing that - I'll correct it now.