# how to change SeekBar's progress asynchronously with audio's current duration Android?

Tags: android, media-player, progress, seekbar

Like in title. I have no idea how may do it. I know that i can use

```
mSeekBar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentDuration());
```

but i don't know how to implement some listener which listen to current duration changes. I using MediaPlayer, that class provide a lot of listeners but not that.

Comment: unfortinatly, gomino's answer is really the best solution for that.  altough it's seems required - there is no such API for registering to progress change in the media player.   sad but true.  you should accept @gomino solution

Comment: "sad but true" - accurate summary :d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001044/795245)

The main idea is to use a handler that recursively calls itself if appropriate.
And [here](http://monstercodz.blogspot.fr/2012/06/media-player-with-progress-bar-example.html) is a blog post that may help you just do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I control music playback inside a Service. In order to update my seekbar's progress while the music is playing, I create a worker Thread that asks the Service for the song's current progress so long as my MediaPlayer is not null and it's current position is less that it's total duration. Then I update my seekbar's progress every second and textviews next to it with a Handler.

```
public void updateSeekBar() {

    // Worker thread that will update the seekbar as each song is playing
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Log.d(TAG, "Updating Seekbar.....");
            int currentPosition = 0;
            int total = (int) PlayerService.getInstance().getDuration();
            seekBar.setMax(total);
            while (PlayerService.getInstance().mp != null
                    && PlayerService.getInstance().mp.getCurrentPosition() < total) {
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition = PlayerService.getInstance().mp
                            .getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }

                seekBar.setProgress(PlayerService.getInstance().mp
                        .getCurrentPosition());

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setTimeLeft();
                        setTime();

                    }
                });

            }

        }

    };
    t.start();

}
```