# How to reset the seekbar

Tags: java, android

I have a program with 10 songs 
When  I click on one of the songs the seekbar start moving 
But the problem is when I click on another song seekbar doesn't go back and start moving again it just stop where the first song has stopped

So how can I reset the seekbar when I click on another song

```
    public class on extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer x;
int tx1;
mythread my = new mythread();
private SeekBar seekbar;
class mythread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (x != null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            seekbar.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    seekbar.setProgress(x.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_on);
    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button f = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button g = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button h = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button i = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button j = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            tx1 = progress;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            x.seekTo(tx1);
        }
    });
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onone);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            x.start();
            my.start();
        }

    });
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.ontwo);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            x.start();
            my.start();
        }
    });

    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onthree);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            x.start();
            my.start();
        }
    });
    d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onfour);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            my.start();
            x.start();
        }
    });
    e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onfive);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            my.start();
            x.start();
        }
    });
    f.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onsix);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            my.start();
            x.start();
        }
    });
    g.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onseven);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            my.start();
            x.start();
        }
    });
    h.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.oneight);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            my.start();
            x.start();
        }
    });
    i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onnine);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            my.start();
            x.start();
        }
    });
    j.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            x = MediaPlayer.create(on.this, R.raw.onten);
            seekbar.setMax(x.getDuration());
            my.start();
            x.start();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (x != null) {
        x.stop();
    }
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (x != null) {
        x.stop();
        x.release();
        x = null;
    }
}}
```

and I tried to do this method in every onClick

```
public void resetseek(){
    if(seekbar.getProgress() > 0)
    {
        seekbar.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: post some code, you are saying that `seekbar.setProgress(0);` didn't work and make sure to replace `seekbar` with your own var name

Comment: I see that you posted code as an answer below. Edit your question and insert the code in there instead

Answer (score 0):

Normally one would use

```
seekbar.setProgress(0);
```

to reset a progress bar it to it's initial position.

I see you have posted your code as an answer instead of editing your question.

One big issue with your code is that you call `Thread.start()` more than once, which is illegal.

Also I wouldn't update the ProgressBar in a separate thread, instead you could just do it on the UI thread.

An alternate approach can be read in this question [MediaPlayer, ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000400/mediaplayer-progressbar)