# Show Progress Bar while audio file is Playing?

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, android-mediaplayer

hope finding a solution to my problem , so I have a progress bar showing when clicking on ListView item and while audio file is playing , the problem is when the audio file finish playing the app crashes and gives me this error in logcat:

> 12-11 14:32:17.330 6190-6216/com.example.android.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
>       Process: com.example.android.app, PID: 6190
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.android.app.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:371)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

here's the code for the progress bar :

```
 Runnable _progressUpdater;
private void createProgressParentThread() {

    _progressUpdater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                try
                {
                    int current = 0;
                    int total = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    progressBarParent.setMax(total);
                    Log.d("ThangTB", "total:"+total);
                    progressBarParent.setIndeterminate(false);

                    while(mMediaPlayer!=null  && current<total){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(200); //Update once per second
                            current = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                            //Removing this line, the track plays normally.
                            progressBarParent.setProgress(current);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        } catch (Exception e){

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //Don't want this thread to intefere with the rest of the app.
                }
            }
            if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ThangTB", "callllllllllllllllll");
                    GONELAYOUT();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(_progressUpdater);
    thread.start();
}


public void GONELAYOUT(){
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBarParent.setProgress(0);
            linearLayout_contentProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

public void VISIBLELAYOUT(){
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBarParent.setProgress(0);
            linearLayout_contentProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

and I call these method inside the onItemClick :

```
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                VISIBLELAYOUT();
                createProgressParentThread();
```

Comment: [Personally, I start off a Thread that checks getCurrentPosition() every 200ms or so until the onCompletion() event gets fired off:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000480/10776023)

Comment: where is line 371 of MainActivity?

Comment: @IntsabHaider the line is             371    while(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {try
                
                    int current = 0;
                    int total = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    progressBarParent.setMax(total);
                    Log.d("ThangTB", "total:"+total);
                    progressBarParent.setIndeterminate(false);

Comment: Basically your mMediaPlayer is Null at that time

Comment: Add full code of activity it will be easy to tack why its going to be null

Comment: So ended up by testing on the mediaplayer duration by replacing `while(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())`  with `while(current<total) :D

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this code block starting from line 371,

```
while(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
int current = 0; 
int total = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
progressBarParent.setMax(total); 
Log.d("ThangTB", "total:"+total);
progressBarParent.setIndeterminate(false);
```

Comment: when I replaced it I got this error  12-11 15:08:34.926 6775-6805/com.example.android.appE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.android.app, PID: 6775
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
        at com.example.android.app.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:371)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)