# How would you hook up a progressBar to a song?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-progressbar

My progressBar should be hooked up to a song, where it shows its progression when it is playing. It has occurred to me that I really don't know how to achieve this, thus my code may look ridiculous to some of you.

```
//Find  view By Id for PROGRESS / SEEK BAR,Button
        val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.myLastBar) as ProgressBar
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.playMyLastBreath) as Button
        if(progressBar != null) {
           // progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }

            //On Click for Button
            btn.setOnClickListener {

                //Set button clickable false to stop multiple clicks at a time
                btn.isClickable = false

                //Thread to change status of progress bar
                var status = 0   //Initial status of progress bar

                Thread(Runnable {

                    while (status < 100) {

                        status += 1

                        //if error occurs, then it will handle in try-catch block.

                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(30)
                            progressBar.setProgress(status)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {

                            Log.e("Error", e.message)
                        }

                    }

                    //Set button clickable true after progress complete
                    btn.isClickable = true

                }).start()

            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MediaPlayer, ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000400/mediaplayer-progressbar)

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you expect the progress bar to do and how it's failing.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you expect the progress bar to do and how it's failing.