# Slider progress for Media Player

Tags: android, slider, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer

I am implementing a audio player using **mediaplayer**. In **jetpack compose**, there is **Slider** which only accepts **float** value but **duration** and **currentPostion** of MediaPlayer is Int, even though I convert to float it will not get 100% of progress.
Also I want to implement a seekbar in slider whenever I move the seekbar it move the current position of MediaPlayer too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032046/hook-compose-slider-to-mediaplayer does this help?. its float i guess

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to get the position of the running video/media from moving the `Slider`, consider this, assuming you are computing and setting the media position as seconds, just multiply the slider value to your duration(seconds).

```
@Composable
fun SliderSample(mediaDuration: Int) {

    var sliderValue by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    Slider(
        value = sliderValue,
        onValueChange = {
            sliderValue = it
        }
    )

    val seekDuration = sliderValue * mediaDuration

    // replace this log statement with the media that accepts an integer seconds
    Log.e("SliderValue", "${seekDuration.toInt()}")
}
```

```
setContent {
     SliderSample(180) // 3 minutes
}
```